# I want to change modifiers shortcuts

Tags: shortcut

There is a very handy shortcuts that I can't find how to adjust for myself. So, when you are in "Add Modifier" tab(pic), you can press button to automatically add a modifier, pressing "B" will add a Bevel, for "A" it's an Array and for "S" it's a Soli... no, it's a Mesh Sequence Cache ._. I know there is some direct shortcuts available, like ctrl + 1-2-3 for subdivision, but if anyone could know how to change some of those in **that specific window**, that would be great. [image]